# Oracle 12c sales_history sample schema installation

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am installing sample schema for oracle 12c (12.2). the hr schema installed fine but the sales_order and the other schema are failing. 
The failure is only happening for the pluggable database, especially at

```
specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: sys/password@techfuturepdb as sysdba*
```

Before running the sample schema script

```
SQL> show pdbs 
    CON_ID CON_NAME           OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
     3 TECHFUTUREPDB          READ WRITE NO
```

What is the connect string? What value is it expecting? My tnsnames.ora file is below

-- Installing sample schema sales_history

```
SQL> @?/demo/schema/sales_history/sh_main.sql

specify password for SH as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: password
specify default tablespace for SH as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: users
specify temporary tablespace for SH as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: temp
specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: password
specify directory path for the data files as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/sales_history
writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/log
specify version as parameter 7:
Enter value for 7: v3
specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: sys/password@techfuturepdb as sysdba    
Session altered.

DROP USER sh CASCADE
         *
ERROR at line 1:

ORA-01918: user 'SH' does not exist

old   1: CREATE USER sh IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new   1: CREATE USER sh IDENTIFIED BY password
User created.

old   1: ALTER USER sh DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs
new   1: ALTER USER sh DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
old   2:  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new   2:  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users

User altered.

old   1: ALTER USER sh TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new   1: ALTER USER sh TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
User altered.

Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.
Grant succeeded.

ERROR:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected

ERROR:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/psh_v3.sql"

SQL>
```

here is my tnsnames.ora file

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

TECHFUTURE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = cisnet-10.elom.tg)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = techfuture.elom.tg)
    )
  )

LISTENER_TECHFUTURE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = cisnet-10.elom.tg)(PORT = 1522))

TECHFUTUREPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = cisnet-10.elom.tg)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TECHFUTUREPDB)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

According to section 2.3 the README file in the [GitHub distribution](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest):

> Verify the connect string for the database. For illustration 
>   purposes, the value of  for database pdb is:
>
> ```
> connect_string: localhost:1521/pdb
> ```
>
> The connect_string may also be a valid tnsnames.ora entry.

So you only need to give it the TNS alias:

```
specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: techfuturepdb
```

or if you prefer the EasyConnect equivalent:

```
specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: cisnet-10.elom.tg:1522/techfuturepdb
```

Comment: Thank you. I use this one and it works 
cisnet-10.elom.tg:1522/techfuturepdb

Now I am having unable to open file issue though the sql file has 777 permissions on it.

Connected.


Session altered.


Session altered.


SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"


SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_v3.sql"


SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/psh_v3.sql"

SQL>

Answer (score 1):

I found the other mistake, which could be a reason for this

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql" 
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/lsh_v3.sql" 
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/psh_v3.sql"
```

Which is

> writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 6:
> Enter value for 6: `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/log`

**Solution:** There needs to be forward-slash after log, like this:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/demo/schema/log/
```

It is mentioned in the installation documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001

> Enter the directory path, for example, `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/`, for your log directory: